# Pig Can't Create (or Find) a pigjobs file in HDFS (riskfactor.pig)

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using the HortonWorks sandbox on Azure and I'm working on the Getting Starting with Hadoop tutorial "Lab 3 - Pig Risk Factor Analysis."

http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/hello-world-an-introduction-to-hadoop-hcatalog-hive-and-pig/#section_5

After following all of the steps to the point where this pig script is run:

```
a = LOAD 'geolocation' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = filter a by event != 'normal';
c = foreach b generate driverid, event, (int) '1' as occurance;
d = group c by driverid;
e = foreach d generate group as driverid, SUM(c.occurance) as t_occ;
g = LOAD 'drivermileage' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
h = join e by driverid, g by driverid;
final_data = foreach h generate $0 as driverid, $1 as events, $3 as totmiles, (float) $3/$1 as riskfactor;
store final_data into 'riskfactor' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

Clicking execute starts the job, however it fails nearly immediately with the following error:

File does not exist: /tmp/.pigjobs/riskfactorpig_14-02-2016-22-29-58/stdout at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:71) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:61) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1821) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1792) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1705) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:588) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:365) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java) at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616) at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969) at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2137) at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2133) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657) at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2131)

There are no files at all in the HDFS for /tmp/.pigjobs/.  So it's as if the Pig script needs to create a file there in order to execute and then can't find it.  I'm using the "-useHCatalog" argument and "executing on tez."

Not sure if this is a permissions error, or an Azure error, but it's been extremely frustrating to just be starting out with Tutorials and not have the "sandbox" be set up to get through the first few lessons without having to make innumerable tweaks to the configuration settings. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Through some additional trial and error I learned that by right clicking on the /tmp/.pigjobs folder I may set the permissions for that folder in the HDFS. By default two of the three "write" options are unselected.  Turning on all of the permissions options allowable pig to save and recall the file that it needed to execute the job.